metpy.interpolate cross_section function returns nans in wrong places?
I'm working with metpy.interpolate as I need to extract a diagonal cross section from an .nc file. However, when I do plot the cross section, I get gaps/nans in areas there should be data. Switching from linear to nearest interpolation doesn't help. Attached is the image of the gaps - gaps are expected at the bottom (sea bottom), but not floating around. Any help?

import numpy as np
import xarray as xr
from metpy.interpolate import cross_section
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


y1 = 45.391760
x1 = 12.82280
y2 = 40.690076
x2 = 18.832323


nc = xr.open_dataset("SST_JADRAN.nc")
nc = nc.sel(time=nc.time.dt.year == 1998) # reducing the size of the file
nc = nc.sel(depth = nc.depth < 1250) # limiting the depth
nc = nc.metpy.parse_cf().squeeze().set_coords('depth')
nc = nc.metpy.parse_cf().squeeze().set_coords('time')


start = (x1, y1)
end = (x2, y2)

cross = cross_section(nc, start[::-1], end[::-1], interp_type = "nearest").set_coords(('latitude', 'longitude'))

Here a dummy dataset.

Digging into this really needs the data file. Is it publicly accessible or can you share it somewhere?

Hi! Thanks for the response, I'll upload a dummy example of the dataset in a few hours. It's temperature data from Copernicus, so there shouldn't be gaps in those places.

I have added a smaller dataset. Could you please take a look at it? Thanks!

Using the posted data file with the code above is giving me a ValueError. Is it working for you?

Sorry, I've reuploaded the file, it should work now.

Checked the data again, original data has gaps in it... Thank you for your help!
